# Access to input values created by javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form within a table with Title and description columns and the rows can be added dynamically by a button. I need to access and save the input values in text boxes created by javascript function when saving the form by save button. the input values are later saved on local storage. The saved values are used to repopulate the form in case of unsuccessful validation.

```js
function add_text_input() {
  var table = document.getElementById('mytable');
  var x = table.rows.length;
  table.insertRow(-1).innerHTML = '<tr>' +
    '<td> <input type="text" id="title' + x + '" /></td>' +
    '<td> <input type="text" id="description' + x + '" /></td></tr>';
}

function save_data() {
  var table = document.getElementById('mytable');
  var tableRows = table.rows.length;
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= tableRows; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      var title = document.getElementById('title' + i).value;
      var desc = document.getElementById('description' + i).value;
      var temp = {
        title: title,
        description: desc
      };
      data.push(temp);
    }
  }
  window.localStorage.setItem('Table1', JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table id="mytable">
    <tr>
      <td> Title </td>
      <td> Description </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="button" onclick="add_text_input()" value="add row">
  <input type="button" onclick="save_data()" value="save">
</form>
```

Comment: So.. what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

did you mean something like this?

```
$(document).ready(()=>{ 

    $('#container').append('<input id="addedTxt" type="text" />');
  $('#addedTxt').val('Test');

    $('#saveBtn').on('click', ()=>{
        alert($('#addedTxt').val());
  });

});

<div id="container">

</div>
<input id="saveBtn" type="button" value="save" />
```

(using jquery)

https://jsfiddle.net/u6vnxwzc/1/#&togetherjs=rQ2b5IsJQ1

or where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your code why you use the second For loop? I think it is not necessary.

find the working code snippet

https://s.codepen.io/mastersmind/debug/VNyKrY/DqADdKoRXEjA

```js
function add_text_input() {
  var table = document.getElementById('mytable');
  var x = table.rows.length;
  table.insertRow(-1).innerHTML = '<tr>' +
    '<td> <input type="text" id="title'+x+'" /></td>'+
    '<td> <input type="text" id="description'+x+'" /></td></tr>';
}
function save_data(){
  var table = document.getElementById('mytable');
  var tableRows = table.rows.length;
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= tableRows-1; i++) {
    var title = document.getElementById('title'+ i).value;
    var desc = document.getElementById('description'+ i).value;
    var temp = {title: title, description: desc};
    data.push(temp);
  }
  window.localStorage.setItem('Table1', JSON.stringify(data));
}

loadData = function(){
  let data = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('Table1'));
  for(i=0; i<data.length;i++){
    add_text_input();
    document.getElementById('title'+ (i+1)).value = data[i].title;
    document.getElementById('description'+ (i+1)).value = data[i].description;
  }
}


loadData();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <table id="mytable">
        <tr>
            <td> Title </td>
            <td> Description </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="button" onclick="add_text_input()" value="add row">
    <input type="button" onclick="save_data()" value="save">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```